# How to restrict entry of numbers but allow all the special characters and alphabets in EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How to restricts all the number input but allow all the special characters and alphabets in an editText in an android. I searched but didn't get what I am looking for.

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/country"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Enter your country"                        
             android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions|text"
                    android:textColor="@color/editTextColor"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `InputFilter`.

```
EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.et);
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Android-Validator](https://github.com/throrin19/Android-Validator) library and use Regex to validate input. There're many built-in validator or you can write your owns

```
Validate usernameValid = new Validate(editUsername);
RegExpValidator userNameRegex = new RegExpValidator(mContext, R.string.validator_string_contain_number);
userNameRegex.setPattern("/^([^0-9]*)$/"); // Regular Expression for String not contain numbers.
```

And you will get this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `android:digits=""` in xml if you want to do it **without using regex**. Include all the characters you want to be added